# Can relative (or even absolute) quotient size be calculated from a list of polynomials which are multiples of a given variable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I am working on a Diophantine equation in integers $x$ and $y$. The equation has been solved, so I already know the solutions (there are four) — I am trying to find a more elementary solution.

Through various assignments and [rational] transformations, I’ve derived a number of polynomials in $x$, $y$, and six additional integer parameters ($p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, $t$, and $k$). I’ve found many polynomials that equal zero, in terms of three or more parameters: $krs−kpr+r+q−k=0$ and $kr^2s − r^2 − qr − kr − kq + k^2 = 0$ and so on. I’m trying to use these polynomials together in order to force constraints on the original numbers $x$ and $y$, with the intention of solving the original equation.

My question is this: If I know that $p$ divides $6r+q+3k$ and $krs-5r-4k$ and $k^2+kq-5r^2$ and $r^2s+2r+2k$ and any number of other “polynomial multiples of $p$”, but I don’t necessarily know a simple expression for the quotient — and I certainly “can’t know” [*a priori*] the exact integer quotient, since that’s what I’m trying to prove! — are there methods of combining these “multiples of $p$” in order to prove (e.g.) that $6r+q+3k=krs-5r-4k$ [which would lead to the known solution the original equation]?

Is there, for example, a “Chinese Remainder Theorem” for polynomials, or some similar way of reducing all these equations to hard numbers?

Obviously, if I could find a “zero polynomial” in a single variable, that would be sufficient to finish the proof. Unfortunately, I’ve been able to find “zeros” in any number of *three-variable* combinations (e.g., $y$ and $r$ and $k$, or $p$ and $s$ and $k$, or $y$ and $p$ and $s$), but am finding it essentially impossible to reduce that to even two variables, much less a single variable.

What method(s) should I be looking into?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $p > 3$,  $6 r + q + 3 k \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is equivalent to $r \equiv -q/6 - k/2 \mod p$, and you can substitute that in to $krs−5r−4k \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or any other polynomial equation mod $p$ to get a congruence that doesn't mention $r$.  But you're not going to get any equation that is not mod $p$: any set of polynomial equations mod $p$ that has a solution will have infinitely many solutions.  So I don't see how you could possibly conclude some expression $= 0$, rather than just $\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: I’ve done that, which is how I’ve gotten so many “polynomial multiples”. For example, two-variable $p$-multiples include $4t^2-16r^2t+25r^4$ and $9r^2+6qr+2q^2$ and $r^2s^2-2rs+2$ and so on. I just can’t seem to “close the deal”. But perhaps you’re right, and it just can’t be done. My intuition just tells me that there’s some clever use of divisibility and magnitude constraints (e.g., I know that $p>s>r$, and $k>r$, etc.) that should be sufficient to deduce a “full zero”.

Comment: Maybe you can help me find a way to combine the “zero polynomials” I have, rather than just the “polynomial multiples”? Would you be open to me emailing you about it?

Comment: p.s. I just noticed that we may live in the same city (?), and also have UBC in common (that’s where I did my B.Mus.)! :)